undefined reference to feild in header file error when compiling code with g++
I am trying to compile c++ code using g++, but it could not find defenition of btmptools::new_RGBA_bitmap(...), which is in btmptools.cpp
main.cpp includes btmptools.h and btmptools.cpp includes.
main.cpp:
#include <iostream>

#include "../btmp_tools/btmptools.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    btmptools::bitmap& bitmap_ptr = *btmptools::new_RGBA_bitamp(100*100, 100);
}

btmptools.h:
/* skipping some code */
namespace btmptools
{
    struct bitmap
    {
        vector<std::byte> data;
        unsigned width;
        std::byte channels;
    };
    /* some unnecessary code skipped */
    [[nodiscard]] bitmap* new_RGBA_bitamp(auto pixel_number, auto w);
    
    // ...
};

btmptools.cpp:
#include "btmptools.h"

#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

[[nodiscard]] btmptools::bitmap* btmptools::new_RGBA_bitamp(auto pixel_number, auto w)
{
    btmptools::bitmap nw_btmp;
    nw_btmp.channels = 4;
    nw_btmp.width = w;
    nw_btmp.data = vector<std::byte>(pixel_number*4);
    return &nw_btmp;
}


to compile I use following command:
g++ -std=c++20 main.cpp ../btmp_tools/btmptools.cpp


(-std=c++20 is necessary to use)
and it returns this error:
main.cpp:(.text+0x17): undefined reference to `btmptools::bitmap* btmptools::new_RGBA_bitamp<int, int>(int, int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I tried to use arguments after g++ in different order, and adding -o main or moving btmptools.cpp and btmptools.h in same directory as main.cpp
but nothing works

auto as a function parameter type makes the function a function template.
